# can I use the same Controller that I have used for a CRUD, for a RESTFUL API in laravel?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-5

can I use the same Controller that I have used for a CRUD, for a RESTFUL API in laravel? if so, would you give me a short example how to do it? any part of the CRUD returns a view but the RESTFUL API doesn't, is it possible to use the same controller for both of them?

Comment: yes, you can but you shouldn't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using this approach:

```
if( $request->wantsJson()){
    return response()->json(['your response as json']) 
}else{
    return view('....') 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible as @Sletheren suggested, but it's not a good practice because your code can become long and difficult to read.

The better approach here is to perform the logic in a Business or Service layer and both controllers (CRUD & Restful API) use that class to get the data,